# Unity UI with different screen sizes

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-ui

I am making a game and have a problem with UI. I made it to scale with the screen size. In 16:9 it looks as I want to:
[UI is where I want it to be.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j58NM.png)

But when I switch to 2160 x 1080 I have a problem.
[My UI is outside my game screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jzws.png)

I want that my UI on 18:9 stays in the same position as in 16:9. Any solutions to make it stay inside game bounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Canvas` object -> `Canvas Scaler` component:

Scale With Screen Size
Match = 0 (0 for vertical app, 1 for landscape)

And then you need to change anchors for ui objects to align not from borders, but from center.

Comment: If you have vertical game then Size Match = 0. You need to change anchors for ui objects to align not from borders, but from center

Answer (score 0):

If you want UI to cover entire page make sure you hold shif + alt and select the stretch preset Unity will always cover the entire screen irrespective to resolution

[Unity anchor preset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCel6.png)

[refrence](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/UIBasicLayout.html)